# Google Maps API asynchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working with the Google Maps API. I use the globalFunction when user click on some button. The "calcRoad" function generate the road by using the Google Maps API, and then "Myfunction" use the data from "calcRoad" to do some calculation.

My problem is that right now "Myfunction" doesn't wait "calcRoad" to end before starting. I asume that some of the Google API requests are asynchronous but I can't access the code behind it.

How could I forced "Myfunction" to wait until "calcRoad" is done ?

```
function globalFunction(){
   calcRoad(true,latitude, longitude);
   Myfunction();
}

function calcRoad(bool,lat,long) {  
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var date = new Date();  
    // Add a waypoint
    if(bool){
        var tampon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
        waypoints.push({
            location: tampon,
            stopover:false
        });
    }

    var request = {
        origin: departure_place.geometry.location,
        destination: arrival_place.geometry.location,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[mode],
        waypoints: waypoints,
        avoidHighways: false,
    }; 

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

PS: I tried to use some setTimeout before calling "Myfunction" and it is working but as I don't know how long will the "calcRoad" take to finish (depending on users' parametres) I can't use setTimeout.

I hope that I'm clear with my probleme, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a callback parameter in your calcRoad function :

```
function globalFunction(){
   calcRoad(true,latitude, longitude, Myfunction);
}

function calcRoad(bool,lat,long, cb) {  
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var date = new Date();  
    // Add a waypoint
    if(bool){
        var tampon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
        waypoints.push({
            location: tampon,
            stopover:false
        });
     }

    var request = {
        origin: departure_place.geometry.location,
        destination: arrival_place.geometry.location,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[mode],
        waypoints: waypoints,
        avoidHighways: false,
    }; 

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            cb && cb(); // Check if "cb" callback function is defined and execute it
        }
    });
}
```

Something like this should work !

Comment: I tried to use a callback function but Myfunction still execute before calcRoad (and directionsService) finished their work..

Comment: Ok that's weird ! Did you pass it without execute it ?

Comment: I mean like this : `calcRoad(true,latitude, longitude, Myfunction);`
An not like this : `calcRoad(true,latitude, longitude, Myfunction());`

Comment: It work when using Myfunction instead of Myfunction() ! Thanks !